# search multiple using Filters in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

we have a application that generates a file everyday with .log, have a requirement to search only files from 2018-01-03.log to 2018-01-07.log. How to restrict filter to only those files

I have tried keeping in Filters "2018-01-0[3-7]*" but its not working.

Comment: There's no regex for the file names filter. Best you can do is to create a folder, move those files to it and then do your search on that folder.